# Printing a table as two parts in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing, html-table

I should print a table, but Table doesn't fit paper. I have to print as two parts. how do I do?

Please help me.

Comment: add more details, code .......

Comment: I doubt that there is any way to tell what size paper the user has selected, but using the the CSS page-break-before and page-break-after options you should be able to at least configure your webpage to print OK on standard paper sizes like A4 (and whatever the US equivalent is).

Comment: HTML printing is troublesome at best.  You can insert page breaks, but there is really no function built in that allows you full control of the output.  On another note, a more descriptive question would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`THEAD`, `TFOOT`, and `TBODY` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) may solve the problem without the need for javascript.  Here's a quote from the W3C documentation:

> Table rows may be grouped into a table
>   head, table foot, and one or more
>   table body sections, using the THEAD,
>   TFOOT and TBODY elements,
>   respectively. This division enables
>   user agents to support scrolling of
>   table bodies independently of the
>   table head and foot. When long tables
>   are printed, the table head and foot
>   information may be repeated on each
>   page that contains table data.

Note that, if included, `tfoot` must come before `tbody`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1 heading</th>
      <th>Col 2 heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1 footer</th>
      <th>Col 2 footer</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1 data</td>
      <td>Col 2 data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1 data</td>
      <td>Col 2 data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The rows in `thead` should be repeated at the top of the table on each page when the table is printed.  Similarly, the rows in `tfoot`, if included, should be printed at the bottom of the table on each page when the table is printed.  It's up to the user agent (e.g., the browser) to do this, but I think most modern browsers handle this properly - it's not something I've ever tested though.  I'd be interested to know how you get on.